# Exception to general rules in ul

Tags: css, html-lists

I have some general rules for an ul. Then I want to create a different ul with just a few things different. I just give it an id, but it does not seem to work. I do not understand why?

Here is the example to check: http://jsfiddle.net/n8TVY/

HTML:

```
<ul class="language">
    <li><a href="#">Catal&agrave;</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fran&ccedil;ais</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
/* GENERAL */
a { outline:0; text-decoration: none ; color:grey }

ul {
    margin:40px auto;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
}

ul li {
    position: relative;
    padding: 7px 17px; 
    margin-right: 10px;
    border:1px solid;
    border-color:grey;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul li a {
    display:block; 
}

/* LANGUAGE */
.language ul li {
    margin:0px;
    background-color:blue; 
    border:1px solid;
    border-bottom:0px; border-top:0px; 
    border-color:#ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it should be `ul.language` not `.language ul`

the first means a `ul` with a class of `language`, the second is an element with a class of `language` that contains a `ul`

http://jsfiddle.net/n8TVY/1/

Comment: I specially appreciate the explanation. I learned something new

Answer (score 2):

use to this

```
ul.language li{margin:0px;
background-color:blue; 
border:1px solid;
border-bottom:0px; border-top:0px; 
border-color:#ddd;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/n8TVY/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS should be:

```
ul.language li {
     margin:0px;
     background-color:blue; 
     border:1px solid;
     border-bottom:0px; border-top:0px; 
     border-color:#ddd;
}
```